# Erroneous sym type , code uncompileable

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class muse{
// this plays music files

  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread music, Throwable ex) {
    System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex);
  }};

  String dian="yun.wav";

  static void mate(String dian)
  {
    Thread music = new Thread(dian)
    {
      public void run(String dian)
      {
        try
        {
          Clip clip= null;
          File in = new File(dian);
          AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
          clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          clip.open(audioInputStream);
          clip.start();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click OK to stop music");
          clip.drain();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex)
        {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    music.start();
  }

}
```

I created this code so that I could input the name of the song file in another .java file however the code ended up being uncompilable even though there is no red errors in netbeans.
If i remove the static void mate(String dian){}
The code works fine, can anybody help explain why it doesnt compile or an alternative that allows the code to run from another .java file

Comment: Please post the full error you receive upon compiling. Also, please try and reformat the code you posted to include indentation.

Comment: *however the code ended up being uncompilable even though there is no red errors in netbeans.* What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The `music` object declared in the static method `mate`, is declared locally and is not reachable in your main method.

Try to modify your example:

```
static Thread mate(String diane) {
    return new Thread(dian){
    ...
}
```

and then in your main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread music = mate("filename");
    music.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compilation failure can happen at

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
       mate(dian);
       music.start();
}
```

because *music* variable is not defined in a scope that is accessible to the main().

Easy hack you can make the *Thread music* variable a private static variable, so the main can access it.

```
private static String dian = "yun.wav";
private static Thread music = null;

static void mate(String dian){
          music = new Thread(dian){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors or mistakes with your code:

1) music was not visible to main method, you can declare that as a class variable be visible

2) you are passing an argument to run()(now it is not overriding Thread class method) so when you call start() on music it will do nothing as it will call Thread class Run method. that's why you need to remove String argument passed to run().

3) you were hardcoding file name. you can take it as input from command line.

```
class muse{
    //music will be available to main method
    private static Thread music ;
    // this plays music files

    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread music, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex);
    }
    };

     static void mate(String dian){
    music = new Thread(dian){

    //removed argument so it can run when you call start(); 
    @Override
    public void run(){

      try{
        Clip clip= null;
        File in = new File(dian);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click OK to stop music");
        clip.drain();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    }; 
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
     String dian=null;
        //you can take dian as inut file from command line also using scanner
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        dian=s.next();
        s.close();
        ////////////

        //call Mate() so it will create a new new music thread with clip assigned to dian;  
    mate(dian);
    //start music
    music.start();
    }
    }
```